# best way to do large number of vector computations with gpgpu?

Tags: java, opencl, gpgpu, jocl, jcuda

I have a matrix of 1 million columns x 1 million rows.

**My algoritm needs to do:**

```
Matrix m  = Matrix(rows,cols)
for (colB: cols){
  vector currColA = m.getcolumn(colA)

  for (colB: cols){
    vector currColB = m.getcolumn(colB)
    result = currColA.dotProduct(colB)
    return result;
}}
```

**or you could also say:**

```
Vectors [] v  = Vectors[]

for (i: v.length){
  vector v1 = v[i]

  for (i: v.length){
    vector v2 = v[i]
    result = v1.dotProduct(v2)
    return result;
}}
```

My question: what is the proper way to allocate memory and initialize the memory for this problem:
- Should I allocate the memory for the full matrix, initialize it with the full matrix, and then run the algo?
- or should I allocate the memory for a list of vectors, and then loop through this list?
- or else??

My concern is that I would like to minimize transfer times to the gpu. I have tried this sort of computations by modifying the [JCublas hello world example](http://www.jcuda.de/samples/samples.html) for a sgemm operation on 2 vectors but when doing it on my large number of vectors, ended up having transfer times deleting the benefits of the gpu acceleration.

Thx!
PS: implementation could be in any Java library

Comment: Is this a sparse or a dense matrix? A 1 million x 1 million dense matrix of 32 bit integer or floating point values requires 4000 Gb of memory. Not only will that not fit in any GPU memory, it won't fit in the memory of any host system you don't need a dedicated data centre for. What sort of machine are you planning to do this operation on?

Comment: @talonmies I use an array of 250,000 sparse vectors of double values. Length of any vector is 1,100,000. (http://code.google.com/p/matrix-toolkits-java/source/browse/trunk/src/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/SparseVector.java?r=46).The vectors are *very* sparse (10 values on average are filled). At the moment I can run it with multithreading on my laptop with i7-2860, 16Gb but it take a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are enforcing a 1-at-a-time restriction. CPU->GPU copy, wait, compute, GPU->CPU copy, wait. Most people don't realize the implicit waits that memory copies can cause.

Can you pipeline your operations? In other words, does your loop consist of the following?

- CPU->GPU copy
- GPU compute
- GPU->CPU copy

To pipeline this you would use (for example) 4 separate (in order) command queues, issue a non-blocking transfer to the GPU on each queue, issue the kernel execution on each queue, and issue the GPU->CPU copy on each queue, in that order. You have to guarantee both buffers remain valid until the wait (described later). This will allow the GPU to begin computing while the subsequent memory transfers are taking place.

Also, never use blocking memory transfers, always use non blocking. Every so many (8?) transfers, get an event object for the GPU->CPU copy, but wait for the last event object first if this isn't the first iteration. This will throttle your queues and allow you to reuse buffers, but overlapping the operations keeps the transfers and compute overlapped. We're waiting for the transfer 8 iterations ago, so we're not draining the queue. It is important to manage queue depth, excessive workitems cause laggy GUI and workitem starvation.